# How the error of tensorflow will be fix?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying the code of CNN fault detection but it is getting error. I tried pip install tensorflow but that is also not working.
No module named as tf,
How this error will be removed?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi Ameena, welcome on SO. I hope you're going to find an answer for your question. It is a good idea to read something about [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and produce a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [mcve2](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports)

Answer (score 0):

U are using Anaconda enviroment, u must install tensorflow by following this steps:

- `C:> conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.5`
- `C:> activate tensorflow`
- `(tensorflow)C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow`

See [Installing TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install)

Comment: Done all these steps, but still getting the same error.